# Parse Dashboard empty

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-dashboard

Parse Dashboard is empty besides parse is hosted in Heroku, my app is working fine but I am unable to see anything in the parse dashboard on my google chrome. It was working fine until a couple of weeks. I was able to see the dashboard but nothing loads now even I run the dashboard.

Comment: Please provide more information about the problem. With the information available, it is nearly impossible to detect what is wrong. Could you please show us the console when you try to access the Dashboard and your dashboard config file?

Comment: Make sure your redact your master key if you do...